# Remap keys on GNOME3.8 using xmodmap?

Tags: keyboard, gnome3, xmodmap

I want to remap some keys on my keyboard, specifically: page up key to home  and page down to end.

On previous versions of GNOME 3 I just created a `.xinitrc` file that contained:

```
cat .xinitrc 
xmodmap -e "keycode  117 = End"
xmodmap -e "keycode  112 = Home"
```

and that was all.

On GNOME 3.8.4 this file takes no effect, and I have to manually: `bash .xinitrc`, moreover `xmodmap` settings are lost when I restart gnome shell (which I do sometimes because [of a GNOME 3 bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1060052)), and also are lost spuriously from time to time.

What is the proper way to remap keys when using GNOME 3.8?

Comment: Yes, I use gdm3 for login.

Comment: This is an old ticket for F16, but might be related to your issue. https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=845339

Comment: Seems like .xsession is the correct place for these types of changes. Maybe try that?

Comment: these answers are antiquated since gnome-session-properties has been deprecated https://www.stylesen.org/gnome_3x_startup_applications_debian_jessie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Sourcing commands during login

I've not tried either `.xinitrc` or `.xsession` files to do this, but I have done it using a custom launcher that gets run when I login. You can access the dialog that allows you to do this a couple of ways, I usually just launch it from the command line like so.

```
$ gnome-session-properties
```

The GUI looks like this.

[image: ss of gnome session props]

From here you can create your own custom startup launchers and then point them to shell scripts that contain what ever commands you need to invoke. Here I've created my own Dropbox launcher script that gets executed when I log in.

#### Mapping keys to run commands

If on the other hand you're looking to create shortcut key combinations that will launch commands, I've successfully been using [XBindKeys](http://www.nongnu.org/xbindkeys/) on GNOME 3.8.4 for this very purpose.

My use has been modest but I like to create keyboard shortcuts for Nautilus to launch with certain directories opened.

#### Example

You'll need to first make sure the packages `xbindkeys` is installed.

Then you'll need to run the following command, one time only, to create a template `xbindkeys` configuration file.

```
$ xbindkeys --defaults > /home/saml/.xbindkeysrc
```

With the file created you can open it in a text editor and add a rule like this:

```
"nautilus --browser /home/saml/projects/path/to/some/dir"
  Mod4+shift + q
```

With the above change made we need to kill `xbindkeys` if it's already running and then restart it.

```
$ killall xbindkeys
$ xbindkeys
```

Now with this running any time I type <kbd>Mod</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> Nautilus will open with the corresponding folder opened.

#### Why isn't .xsession or .xinit getting sourced

I believe the ultimate issue lies with this post, titled: [Quickly Setting up Awesome with Gnome](http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Quickly_Setting_up_Awesome_with_Gnome). It discusses methods for getting GDM (GNOME's Display Manager) into loading these files, which to me implies that it doesn't by default.

My Fedora 19 system contains this file: `/usr/share/xsessions/gnome.desktop` which contains these lines:

```
Exec=gnome-session
TryExec=gnome-session
Icon=
Type=Application
```

I believe gnome-session doesn't source your `.xsession` file by default, and the `.xinit` is meant to be sourced if you invoke GNOME using `startx`.

Be sure to look through the section titled: [with GDM](http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Quickly_Setting_up_Awesome_with_Gnome#with_gdm), which shows this in more details.

#### References

- [Detect if mouse button is pressed, then invoke a script or command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106736/detect-if-mouse-button-is-pressed-then-invoke-a-script-or-command/106741#106741)
- [XBindKeys](http://www.nongnu.org/xbindkeys/)

Comment: This is a very usefull tool, but I want to do a slightly different thing. In your case you wanted to launch a process when user presses keystrokes, I want application to get different keystroke than it was pressed.

Comment: @jb. - Here I've added a method that I use to run commands such as your `xmodmap` cmds. when I login to my desktop.

Comment: This solves the problem partially: initially shortcuts work, but after restart of ``gnome-shell`` they vanish. 

I'll accept it and wait for fix of gnome-shell freeze bug.

Comment: @jb. - ah yes, darn, thought this had the problem licked.

Comment: @jb. - I too have been suffering the restarts of the gnome-shell. It starts to go crazy with memory utilization and I use this to restart it: `pkill -HUP gnome-shell`. Is that your issue as well?

Comment: Precisely thats it.

Answer (score 2):

In case someone else stumbles upon this, it is properly discussed here: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=873656

Unfortunately `.xmodmap` is not and will not be supported by Gnome 3 anymore.

Users should migrate their configs to `xkb`.