# How can you run a script triggered by a joystick input?

Tags: linux, scripting, joystick

I'm using a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian to power my arcade cabinet. I want to shut the Pi down using the `sudo poweroff` command without using the keyboard. I'm thinking the best way would be to create a simple script that would somehow be triggered by a combination of controller button inputs. It seems easy to bind a keyboard to a script, but not so easy to use a joystick input instead.

Does anyone have any ideas?

#### EDIT #1

The joystick and controller buttons all work fine and show up using the `jstest` tool from the `jstest-gtk` package and all work fine in Mame4all. I haven't tried `xev` but will look into it.

Comment: Are the joystick buttons/movements recognized by `xev`?

Comment: Thanks again for the replies. I have the joystick package installed and jstest recognises all inputs. How exactly do I use the other executables from the package to run a script based on a combination of inputs? Thanks in advance

Comment: Jody, welcome to the site. If you want someone to be notified of a comment, either comment on their post or `@`mention them by name, e.g. @slm. If one of the answers solves your problem, please mark it as [accepted](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Jody, I've updated my answer with some additional info on tools and a  method that shows how you can bind keyboard shortcuts to run a script.

Comment: I have found [this](https://www.piborg.org/joyborg) which appears to get input from each axis via pygame. I have yet to test/adapt it :)

Answer (score 3):

#### xev

I do not believe you can use `xev` to detect joysticks. I'm using Fedora 19 and there is a package called `joystick` which installs this package, `linuxconsoletools`. This project is what you're looking for.

#### linuxconsole project

It contains a number of tools for hooking joysticks up so that their signals are received by the Linux Kernel.

*excerpt from [linuxconsole website](http://sourceforge.net/projects/linuxconsole/)*

> This project maintains the Linux Console tools, which include utilities to test and configure joysticks, connect legacy devices to the kernel's input subsystem (providing support for serial mice, touchscreens etc.), and test the input event layer.

The package includes executables such as these

```
$ rpm -ql linuxconsoletools.x86_64
/usr/bin/ffcfstress
/usr/bin/ffmvforce
/usr/bin/ffset
/usr/bin/fftest
/usr/bin/inputattach
/usr/bin/jscal
/usr/bin/jscal-restore
/usr/bin/jscal-store
/usr/bin/jstest
/usr/libexec/joystick/extract
/usr/libexec/joystick/filter
/usr/libexec/joystick/ident
```

#### Ubuntu

I do not have a Debian installation available but Ubuntu also has the same package, `joystick`. Running the command `apt-file list joystick` shows the same files as the RPM I mentioned above.

#### What else?

I would also suggest taking a look at the ArchLinux Wiki topic titled: [Joystick](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/joystick). It's probably the most exhaustive resource on the topic, related to Linux.

#### Mapping joystick to keyboard

The above will get your joystick working in Linux, but doesn't offer any method for mapping joystick to a script, at least not in a easy fashion. To do something like that you'll need to enlist the help of another application. There is one that I'm familiar with called [`jkeys`](https://code.google.com/p/jkeys/).

You'll need to install some dependencies first to install it, `python-xlib` & `python-pygame`. These should be in most distros' repos.

However to install `jkeys` you'll have to download it from the project's subversion repository. **NOTE:** It's written in Python.

```
$ svn checkout http://jkeys.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ jkeys-read-only
```

After downloading it you can run it like so:

```
$ ./jkeys 
usage: jkeys joystick.conf application [params]
```

To map a key you'll need to create your own `joystick.conf` file:

```
<config>
    <joystick id="0">
        <axis number="0" low="Left" high="Right" />
        <axis number="1" low="Down" high="Up" />
        <button number="0" key="Space" />
        <button number="1" key="Return" />
        <button number="2" key="a" />
        <button number="3" key="b" />
        <button number="4" key="c" />
        <button number="5" key="d" />
        <button number="6" key="z" />
        <button number="7" key="x" />
        <button number="9" key="Escape" />
        <button number="10" key="p" />
    </joystick>
</config>
```

Now when you're ready to run your game you do it like so:

```
$ ./jkeys joystick.py <somegame>
```

The overridden joystick buttons will send whatever key you press instead of the joystick buttons to the app.

#### QJoy

Another alternative is to use the app [QJoyPad](http://qjoypad.sourceforge.net/). I was unable to test this since I have no joystick. The GUI should look like this.

[image: ss of qjoypad]

From this GUI you could map any button presses to keypresses fairly easily.

#### What about running a script?

Well with the above methods you could make use of another application called [XBindKeys](http://www.nongnu.org/xbindkeys/) to map any keyboard presses to run an actual command or script.

**NOTE:** My example below creates a keyboard shortcut so that Nautilus will launch with certain directories opened.

#### Example

You'll need to first make sure the packages `xbindkeys` is installed.

Then you'll need to run the following command, one time only, to create a template `xbindkeys` configuration file.

```
$ xbindkeys --defaults > /home/saml/.xbindkeysrc
```

With the file created you can open it in a text editor and add a rule like this:

```
"nautilus --browser /home/saml/projects/path/to/some/dir"
  Mod4+shift + q
```

With the above change made we need to kill `xbindkeys` if it's already running and then restart it.

```
$ killall xbindkeys
$ xbindkeys
```

Now with this running any time I type <kbd>Mod</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> Nautilus will open with the corresponding folder opened.

#### References

- [Jkeys - simple joystick to keyboard mapping](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=903858)
- [Detect if mouse button is pressed, then invoke a script or command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106736/detect-if-mouse-button-is-pressed-then-invoke-a-script-or-command/106741#106741)
- [XBindKeys](http://www.nongnu.org/xbindkeys/)

Comment: The OP's last comment was for you I think.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comprehensive answer. I think I almost have all I need to do what I want. The final piece of the puzzle is how to map a combination of button presses to a key or to run a script. Thanks again, Jody. Edit: actually, I think you've shown me how to do that already, sorry. I'll have a go and report back. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

I went a little bit different route and developed a lightweight background daemon to run a script once special buttons are pressed:

https://github.com/workinghard/jslisten

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is very old, but I write here as a reference for other users.
I faced the same kind of problem with my Raspberry Pi 4. I wanted to launch a graphical application based on a specific joystick button press.

The solution I came up with is based on the Python module `pygame`. It allows interaction with joystick-triggered events, with rather basic-level scripting.
It allowed me to call the application with

```
os.system("lxterminal -e <application_name>")
```

since in my case the application needed to be launched from terminal. But any kind of scripted command would work, I guess. If you already configured your joystick, you only need some other testing tool to find out the button number you need to check for in the code. As other suggested, `jstest` from the `joystick` package works well.

Probably not the smartest option, but it works and is quite simple if you are a little bit familiar with Python. The "listening" script can also be run automatically in background as a service using `systemd`.