# How to catch keystrokes in Linux environment

Tags: gnome, keyboard-shortcuts, desktop, architecture

I need a C code to be executed when some particular keys are pressed in Linux "Desktop" environment.

What are the ways to register for such an event and How?

Should I write ISR for that? I need an exact part of Linux from where I can get this call.

Which part of OS handles stuff like these, Is it part Desktop environment like GNOME or part of some service?

Comment: Do you want to catch the keycodes within a C application or run an executable when keycodes are pressed?

Comment: @slm run an executable when keycodes are pressed

Comment: Have a look at [`xbindkeys`](http://www.nongnu.org/xbindkeys/)

Comment: Search this site for Q&A's with `xbindkeys` in them. You'll find dozens of examples showing you what you want. If you need something additional from those then I'd rephrase this Q to express the additional criteria. http://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A7453+xdotool

Answer (score 2):

I would try and make use of [`xbindkeys`](http://www.nongnu.org/xbindkeys/) to run a command/script when certain keys are pressed.

To start you can insruct `xbindkeys` to generate a template config file like so:

```
$ xbindkeys --defaults > /home/saml/.xbindkeysrc
```

Then open the resulting config file in any editor and add a line like so:

```
"nautilus --browser /home/saml/projects/path/to/some/dir"
 Mod4+shift + q
```

Then kill and restart `xbindkeys` so that it'll reload the modifications in the config file:

```
$ killall xbindkeys
$ xbindkeys
```

Now with this running any time I type <kbd>Mod</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> Nautilus will open with the corresponding folder opened.

The above can easily be modified so that any script or command could be run instead of the above. This is just an example to illustrate the approach and to get you started.

#### References

- [How can you run a script triggered by a joystick input?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107818/how-can-you-run-a-script-triggered-by-a-joystick-input/107826#107826)

Answer (score 0):

Your desktop environment may have a settings utility to configure keybindings.

**Gnome 3 Shell**

Go to `System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts` and create a `Launcher` shortcut[[1](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Keybindings)].

**KDE**

Go to `System Settings`[[2](http://docs.kde.org/stable/en/kde-workspace/systemsettings/using-kapp.html#starting)]`>  Shortcuts and Gestures > Global Shortcuts`[[3](http://docs.kde.org/stable/en/kde-workspace/systemsettings/general.html)] and assign a custom keybinding, or

Assign a KDE shortcut to your appliation launcher[[4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90567/quickly-launch-any-app-in-kde-with-a-shortcut)].  You may need a .desktop file for your application to use this.

1. Unlock Widgets.
2. Right-click in launcher and click Edit Applications...
3. Find the app you want to assign a shortcut

**Other**

Otherwise you can use `xbindkeys`.  Arch Wiki has a [`xbindkeys` tutorial](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xbindkeys) worth reading.

[[1](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Keybindings)] https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Keybindings 
[[2](http://docs.kde.org/stable/en/kde-workspace/systemsettings/using-kapp.html#starting)] http://docs.kde.org/stable/en/kde-workspace/systemsettings/using-kapp.html#starting 
[[3](http://docs.kde.org/stable/en/kde-workspace/systemsettings/general.html)] http://docs.kde.org/stable/en/kde-workspace/systemsettings/general.html 
[[4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90567/quickly-launch-any-app-in-kde-with-a-shortcut)] https://askubuntu.com/questions/90567/quickly-launch-any-app-in-kde-with-a-shortcut