# Using xkeybinds on headless node for HUID USB Device I/O

Tags: raspbian, headless, xbindkeys

I run Raspberry pi's (rpi) in headless mode running Raspbian - a form of Debian. I would like to use the xev with xkeybinds approach (see [Detect if mouse button is pressed, then invoke a script or command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106736/detect-if-mouse-button-is-pressed-then-invoke-a-script-or-command) for details) as a general method to let USB devices control a headless rpi thru issuing shell commands.

Another method using X is to have a shell script running all the time with constant do while loop that pipes xinput --query-states to grep's loading the state of mouse buttons into variables that are conditionally tested and if true perform shell commands, like shutdown or mpc volume +2 to increase volume.  This should work as I have script that outputs mouse states to the screen.  Comments on this method are most welcome also.

My question is would this work?

Do I need to install all of X org apk's to get this to work?  Which ones?
Do I need an X daemon running all the time in order to have xkeybinds active all the time?  How would I do this?  Do I just have an active xterm all the time or run any X app daemon with the xvfb-run command.

If this works it would be a general method to allow thousands of USB HUID's to control headless rpi's without having to solder GPIO pins and use off the shelf devices.

All input is welcome.